# Java: Threads take a long time to finish, despite doing very simple tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, threadpool, future

I currently have a java program that uses Threadpool and spawns Runnable threads. For some reason, it takes a long time for the threads to finish up, despite them not doing any complex logic.

Here is my thread class...

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    public MyThread(){}

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

And here is where I spawn the threads...

```
public void testThreads(){

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    List<Future<?>> tasks = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        tasks.add(threadPool.submit(new MyThread());

    }

    // Waiting for threads to complete
    for (Future<?> currTask : tasks) {
        try {
            currTask.get();
        } catch (Throwable thrown) {
            context.getLogger().log("Error while waiting for thread completion");
        }
    }

}
```

For some reason, in the For-loop, when I am waiting for all threads to complete, it takes like 10+ seconds. Why is this? Why do the threads take so long to complete?

Comment: The program finishes almost immediately for me. Seeing `context.getLogger().log(...)` makes me think that you're running this from within an AWS Lambda function, and your function timeout is set to 10 seconds. This hanging occurs because you're not shutting down the `ExecutorService`, and its non-daemon threads remain alive, prolonging the execution of the program until it times out.

Comment: I am running it inside a Lambda function, but the timeout is set to like 10 mins. It seems to consistently take around 10-15 seconds to do all this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program hangs because some threads never terminate. In order to properly terminate the program, all non-daemon threads should terminate first
(see the Javadoc for the [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class).

The executor service will start his own (non-daemon) worker threads, which are left running (in waiting state) after all tasks are executed.

In order to ensure the program terminates, call `executorService.shutdown()` to stop its worker threads.

```
public void testThreads() {
  ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
  List<Future<?>> tasks = new LinkedList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tasks.add(threadPool.submit(new MyThread()));
  }
  /*
   * no need to wait on each future- just call shutdown(),
   * the executor will run all pending tasks
   * and will then stop its worker threads
   */
  threadPool.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this shutdown thing standard? Will it affect any of the threads that I need for my java program?

Comment: Once all the threads have been launched, method `shutdown()` can be invoked. You don't have to wait for all the launched threads to complete before invoking method `shutdown()`.

Comment: @DChalo123 see the Javadoc for Thread at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html . The Java program will terminate once all non-daemon threads terminate. Well `shutdown()` is obviously implemented by all `ExecutorService`s... but if you spawn your own threads, you will need to make sure they terminate.

Comment: the point is, there is nothing wrong with your code- the program would simply hang on exit.

Comment: @Abra good point! Anyway I simply wanted to emphasize that the program needs to be properly torn down - and I edited the OP code in the most obvious way.

Comment: Wait, so should i call shutdown before or after the for-loop?

Comment: uhm it doesn't really matter that much - for clarity, I would put the tear down/clean up logic at the end of the method.